# Jmeter 2.10 and oAuth authentication

Tags: oauth, jmeter

Testing APIs authenticated with oAuth with the Jmeter 2.10 and stuck with making it work with oAuth headers.

I found 2 plugins for Jmeter, which suppose to do this, but there are different issues with each of them:

1. https://code.google.com/p/jmeter-oauth/ — throws `NoSuchMethodError` in the logs, and community say that it's due to incompatible versions;
2. http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/OAuthSampler/ — this one is not allowing to send `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret`, which is required on for my API, so authorization fails.

In order to complete request I need to send Authorization headers with 4 oAuth parts. I cannot compose the header manually because it requires signature, generated based on the token and message body.

What other approach can I try?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) using Groovy language.

This component allows you to add custom Groovy code for example and generate the TOKEN variable:

[image: TOKEN Computing]

You can then use the [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) component:
[image: Header Manager config]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by using the following approach:

Configure a keystore with client certificate and key.
Configure SSL Manager with this certificate.
Configure http request with Client Certificate and SSLManager parameters.

The client certificate is the one that contains the private key for the OAuth signature generation.